# R - BigQuery :Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Bad access

Tags: r, excel, google-bigquery

I'm triying to upload into Google Big Query using bigrquery package in R. At the moment I can upload into BigQuery Table successfully running the script in RStudio (without any problem), but the problem is when I calling this script from Excel, the script is stop and then close.

Please see the script below:

```
library(googleAuthR) 
library(bigrquery)

  # Set ID and dataset 
  project_id <- 'FR'
  dataset_name <- 'table_1'
  
  # Upload data into BigQuery
  codifications_upload = bq_table(project = project_id, dataset = dataset_name, table = 'Entry_data')
  bq_table_upload(x = codifications_upload, values = AHS21,create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER', write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')

#AHS21 is a dataframe that i try to upload
```

The error that appers is the following:

```
Error in curl::curl:fetch_memory(url,handle=handle):
Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Bad access
Calls_ bq_table_upload ... request_fetch -> request_fetch.write_memory -> <Anonymous>
```

Comment: Do you use BQ connector for excel https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-connector-for-excel?

Comment: Yes, I have already Simba, inclusive, I bring queries Everyday without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Additionally I would like to share instructions: [1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-connect-bigquery-to-microsoft-excel-and-other-apps-with-our-new-odbc-driver), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpFtx3BTcOA). Let me know if you have followed it. Thanks.